# ElasticSearch, RSS and `_mapping` requirement?

Tags: parsing, plugins, rss, schema, elasticsearch

I want to store RSS feeds in a searchable ElasticSearch store.

Using [RSSRiver](http://www.pilato.fr/rssriver), I am confused as to what they want:

Do they require a `/_mapping` and  a `/_meta`?

So given a nested [RSS feed like this one](http://venturebeat.com/feed), is the approach to write a script to generate `/_mapping` or should it just work?

Here's what I tried, but the server didn't seem to download anything `:\`:

```py
es.put('venture_beat/_meta',
       data={"type": "rss",
              "rss": {"feeds": [{"name": "venturebeat",
                                 "url" : "http://venturebeat.com/feed/"}]}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is more complete here: https://github.com/dadoonet/rssriver

You need to create a _meta document in a specific index _river.

```
$ curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/lemonde/_meta' -d '{
  "type": "rss",
  "rss": {
    "feeds" : [ {
        "name": "lemonde",
        "url": "http://www.lemonde.fr/rss/une.xml"
        }
    ]
  }
}'
```

Don't forget _river index name.

Comment: Thanks, that got me the first 7 news items from the feed. Guessing the amount of data it takes can be configured?

Comment: As far as I remember, RSS River fetch all existing content sent by the RSS service.